# What is the teacher's last name?

Tags: united-states, palaeography, rhode-island

Recently, I found my great-great grandmother's (Emily Griffiths) 5th grade report card from 1895 nailed to the wall in the attic over the garage (don't ask me why it was there, I took it down and put it in a safer place pending my ability to get it preserved).

Anyway, most of it is pretty easy to read, but unfortunately I have always had trouble reading cursive, especially in isolation. I can't read the last name of the teacher (Elizabeth W(?)....ich?), what grade Emily got for "Conduct", or what word is written after "History" under the listing of the various classes. Presumably that word explains why history is the only class were a numerical grade was given.

I have attached two different images showing the report card. Note that I had to reduce the quality so that the file size would be small enough to post on here. Could someone who can read cursive better than I can please identify the indicated words?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The teacher's name is Elizabeth Ullrich.

From the report card, we can see that the school was in Rhode Island.  There is a report titled [RHODE ISLAND SCHOOL REPORT](http://sites.rootsweb.com/~rigenweb//schools9.html), prepared for the Rhode Island Board of Education which lists School Officers and Teachers in Public Schools in 1894-95 which includes Elizabeth Ullrich as a teacher in '*Grammar, Intermediate, Primary, and Ungraded Schools*' in Pawtucket.

---

The grade for 'Conduct' was a C.

The word after History appears to be '*Ectrac*' (presumably short for '*Extracurricular*')

Comment: Great answer, and fast too! Thank you. And thanks for the link to the RI School Report.

Answer (score 2):

Teacher: Ullrich

grade for conduct: C

word after history: extra... [something after extra, but I can't read it]

Answer (score 2):

I think the C for Conduct is clear.

I think the word after History is Extrac. being short for [Extracurricular](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/extracurricular):

> An extracurricular activity or subject is not part of the usual school or college course

The teacher's name is the hardest to read.  I thought it might be Sellick but [@sempaiscuba provides strong evidence for Ullrich](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/14902/19) so I would readily accept that.

Answer (score 0):

Ullrich is the teacher's last name.  Looks like "extra" after "history" (extra credit, it looks like 72 in box).  The student is Emily Grittiths 1894-1895, Pawtucket, RI.  Emily had all A's and B's on this report card.